# How do I specify a Kubernetes service as HTTP target for a Google Cloud task?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I have a nodejs express server running on Google Kubernetes Engine, exposed as a NodePort service at some IP (say 10.0.20.20).

I would like to use this nodejs service as the handler for Google Cloud tasks, so I created the following task (using the Python library):

```
task = {
    'http_request': {
        'http_method': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://10.0.20.20/myendpoint',
        'body': payload
    }
}
```

The task is created successfully, however, it then gets stuck in the queue retrying forever. How can I set up my service so that it is reachable from Google Cloud tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your scenario you want to achieve here is the recommended use of service exposure at GKE level.

I will assume you want to connect into that nodejs service from an instance on the same network as your GKE cluster nodes since you are using an RFC-1918 IP.

A [nodeport](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#service_of_type_nodeport) can only use (as per now) a range from 30000 to 32767.

> You can specify your own nodePort value in the 30000--32767 range. However, it's best to omit the field and let Kubernetes allocate a nodePort for you. This avoids collisions between Services.

So, the url you are using:

> http://10.0.20.20/myendpoint

Is by default using port 80/tcp, and not one of the nodePort range I previously mentioned (30000 to 32767) and therefore, failing.

If you want to use only a pass-through internally from other instances on the same VPC and region, use a service type [loadbalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_loadbalancer), if you want an intermediate services that handles HTTPS for you instead of your backend, use an [internal ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress) but keep in mind that this is still on beta and that you would need to provide your own [SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-ilb#support_for_features) as this is not compatible with Google Managed certs right now.

As a reminder, assuming you are using a stable GKE version cluster, internal loadbalancer service types are considered regional resources meaning you can only use them in the same subnet you create them with a few exceptions being VPN and/or interconnect into the same VPC and subnet region, this behavior will be optional starting from version [1.16](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#global_access) and up.

Comment: The shorter answer is to expose at least a proxy service to reroute the task to target.